# Post Webflow form results to Slack channel

Tags: webhooks, slack, webflow

I am trying to post form results to the Slack channel using webflow and slack apps. So I have created a Slack app that exposes the webhook URL for posting the data to the channel.
I have added the webhook URL to the action field with the method type set to post and published the change.

[image]

When I input the data into the form and trigger the form submit button I get the message: `invalid json payload`.

[image]

So how I can convert the data to string or change the data format so it could be sent to Slack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the easiest no-code solution I'd use [zapier](https://zapier.com)

You can go on slack, and look for its integrations with Webflow.

Or reach this [link](https://zapier.com/sign-up/?referrer=%2Fapps%2Fslack%2Fintegrations%2Fwebflow&next=%2Fapp%2Feditor%2Ftemplate%2F224032%3Freferrer%3D%252Fapps%252Fslack%252Fintegrations%252Fwebflow), I found the integration already. Create an account and set up your webhook. It's free for a single "zap" and it takes 5 minutes to set up

Comment: Is there a solution with code? I am new to webflow so I don't really know how I can extend the functionalities with code

Comment: You'll have to write some backend functionality that is reached by your Action url,

something like /slackHandler.php which then handles that logic. Webflow itself doesn't provide this functionality and they recommend Zapier in a lot of their tutorials. For front-end stuff you can always include HTML embeds and write your own code! For back-end you'll be restricted to what their CMS API can offer, given that you have a site hosted with them